# In-App-Purchase error while purchasing (SKPayment)

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

I'm implementing an In-App-Purchase into my app.
This is my code:

```
 #define kRemoveAdsProductIdentifier @"com.company.myApp.inAppPurchase"

-(void)fetchProducts {

SKProductsRequest *productsRequest = [[SKProductsRequest alloc] initWithProductIdentifiers:[NSSet setWithObject:kRemoveAdsProductIdentifier]];
productsRequest.delegate = (id)self;
[productsRequest start];
}

-(void)productsRequest:(SKProductsRequest *)request didReceiveResponse:(SKProductsResponse *)response {

products = response.products;
NSLog(@"Produkte wurden geladen");
}

-(void)request:(SKRequest *)request didFailWithError:(NSError *)error {

NSLog(@"%@",error);
}


-(void)buy:(SKProduct *)product {

SKPayment *payment = [SKPayment paymentWithProduct:product];
[[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue]addPayment:payment];
}


-(IBAction)removeAdvertisment:(id)sender {

SKProduct *prod = [products objectAtIndex:0];
[self buy:prod];

}

-(void)paymentQueue:(SKPaymentQueue *)queue updatedTransactions:(NSArray *)transactions {

for (SKPaymentTransaction *tx in transactions) {

    switch (tx.transactionState) {
        case SKPaymentTransactionStatePurchased:
            [[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue]finishTransaction:tx];
            bannerImage.alpha = 0.0;
            _adRemoved35.alpha = 1.0;
            _adRemoved4.alpha = 1.0;
            _buttonAd35.alpha = 0.0;
            _buttonAd4.alpha = 0.0;
            [defaults setBool:YES forKey:@"isPro"];
            break;

        case SKPaymentTransactionStateFailed:
            [[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue]finishTransaction:tx];
            NSLog(@"Error: %@",tx.error);
            break;

        case SKPaymentTransactionStateRestored:
            [[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue]finishTransaction:tx];
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }
  }
}
```

In this line of code the error happends:

```
SKPayment *payment = [SKPayment paymentWithProduct:product];
```

console:

```
prod = (ViewController *) 0x14a0dc00
products = (NSArray *) @"0 objects"
```

Does someone knows whats wrong?
Thanks for your answers.

I'm using xCode 6.0.1, iPad 3 with iOS 8.0.2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you check the response of the SKProductsRequest?

It seems like you do not get a valid product list as a response, thus

> products = response.products;

sets wrong values
and

> SKProduct *prod = [products objectAtIndex:0];
>    [self buy:prod];

hands the wrong values over to buy:...

Comment: Thanks for the hint. It was the incorrect identifier. I just have to write the name of the In-App-Purchase and not the whole bundle-ID.

Comment: Ok. Now: `product = (SKProduct*) nil`. The app crashes in this line of code: `[[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue]addPayment:payment];' in the buy method. I tried all but didn't find the error.

Comment: Do you check if SKPayment *payment = [SKPayment paymentWithProduct:product]; sets a valid value for payment? If payment is set to nil at that point that might be causing your error.